One-To-Many relation doen't show child
I have two classes that has one-To-many relation
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade= CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval=true)
 
    private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<>();
}
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
@ToString
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne( cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Parent parent;
}

when I use findAll method in repository for parent class I do not get children even with fetch = FetchType.EAGER, I also tryied LEFT JOIN FETCH and Entity Graph

Parent.childs has type Set<Resource>.  Is that supposed to be Set<Child>?  Otherwise, it's unclear what the two entities presented have to do with each other.

@John Bollinger fixed question. In original code was child

Possibly related: To initialize or not initialize JPA relationship mappings?.  Take especial note of the second answer, which claims that providing an initializer for a relationship field caused issues for the answerer.

I guess you are using the MySQL database.
So if it is so, please check a couple of steps.

check the database for both parent and child
check if adding parent data, is it really adding the child data or not, I think it should.
check the schema of both the database
I can see you are using "strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY" so for parent data there won't be any column named with a child reference but for child data, there will be one column with the parent data reference name "parent_id"
this column will act as a foreign key for parent in child.
check that column, I think for your case it is null. So parent data is unable to get the child reference from the table which is why while fetching the parent data, it is unable to print the child data.


if these assumptions are correct, then please follow a couple of steps

if have to assign the parent reference to child data before persisting to the database manually. this could be done in your service layer itself.

for example, let's say you want to add parent data to the database
public void addData(Parent parentData) {
    Set<Child> childSet = parentData.getChilds();
    for (Child child : childSet) {
        child.setParent(parentData) // manually referencing the parent data to child
    }
    parentRepository.save(parentData);
}


write @JsonBackReference in your parent class for the field child to break the backreference circuit. To know more about this just search it internet
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade= CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval=true)
@JsonBackReference
private Set childs = new HashSet<>();


